# JQuery script interfering with another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html table and i download 2 jquery plugins, one is to have fixed-headers and the other is make the table sortable. They work just fine independently but the issue is when i try to make them work together. Only the FixedHeader function is working. 
I will appreciate any help!

Please I need help, i don't know what else to do:

```
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.SortingColumns, '/__jquery.tablesorter/jquery-latest.js')}"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.SortingColumns, '/__jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js')}"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.FixHeader,'/Fixed-Header/jquery.fixedheadertable.js')}"/>
<script>  
    // Use full jQuery function name to reference jQuery.
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#table-2").fixedHeaderTable({ height: 200 });
        jQuery("#table-2").fixedHeaderTable({ themeClass: 'mytable' }); 
    });
    window.onload = function() {
        $("#table-2").tablesorter(); 
        $("#table-2").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    };
 </script>
```

Table Structure:

```
<table id="table-2" class="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>                                
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `fixedHeaderTable` is probably modifying the DOM to rewrite the table, take a look in the DOM inspector to see what it looks like after it runs. Also, I suggest you run both codes from `$(document).ready()`, rather than mixing that with `window.onload`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I moved eveything in to $(document).ready() but still not working.

Comment: I didn't think that would fix it, it was just a recommendation to avoid confusion (it's not clear what order the two will run with the original code). What did you see when you checked the DOM as I suggested?